# Replace button on email form in CRM 2011

Tags: customization, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Please look at the below E-Mail form.
And you can see one button called **"Insert Template"** highlighted with red color. How can we replace(hide it and add new one) this button with our own custom button like, we can hide the same named button on ribbon through XML...?

[image]

Comment: Hi! I've had situation like this. Unfortunately didn't find solution for completely removing this button. I used next code for hiding that button:

' 
var emailFrame = window.top.document.getElementById('contentIFrame');
var frameDoc = emailFrame.contentDocument || emailFrame.contentWindow.document;

 var el = frameDoc.getElementById('idinserttemplate'); 
 if(el)
 {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
 }
'

Answer (score 1):

That button isn't on the ribbon, it's a part of the rich editor control. There is no supported way to change those buttons that I know, so you'll have to go with some JavaScript as  @lazarus suggested.